# My android login app unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, login-script

My simple app getting unfortunately stopped error.
Kindly solve, please.

I do not need any permissions

Here is my android main activity:

```
package vk.com.login_simple;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
private EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
private Button login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
private Button reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
private Button exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Login App");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void login(View view){
if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin")&&password.getText().toString().equals("password")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//your code here
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Username / Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
    }

    public void reset(View view) {
        username.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Reset success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void exit(){
        //empty
    }
}
```

Comment: Show logcat please

Comment: add the logcat out put

Comment: can you give activity_main.xml

Comment: please add you activity_main.xml

Comment: https://vivekp.co/activity_main.xml


https://vivekp.co/n.txt 
For logcat

Comment: @user8843902 many correct answers below!!!

Comment: Thanks Who Helped For Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById` ONLY work after you `setContentView()` which define the root view of your layout, to show where the Views can be found. If you call it outside Android don't know how and where to find Views for you.

So what you MUST do is place all of the `findViewById()` code inside `onCreate()` and after `setContentView()`.

```
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
private Button reset;
private Button exit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Login App");

        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package vk.com.login_simple;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
private Button reset;
private Button exit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        setTitle("Login App");


    }
    public void login(View view){
if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin")&&password.getText().toString().equals("password")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//your code here
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Username / Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
    }

    public void reset(View view) {
        username.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Reset success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void exit(){
        //empty
    }
}
```

You can use findViewById after they have been created in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Put your parsing inside onCreate() method

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parse inside onCreate method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
private Button reset;
private Button exit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Login App");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    }
}
```

instead of parsing use [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.username)
    private EditText username;
    @BindView(R.id.password)
    private EditText password;
    @BindView(R.id.login)
    private Button login;
    @BindView(R.id.reset)
    private Button reset;
    @BindView(R.id.exit)
    private Button exit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Login App");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize inside onCreate method like belllow

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
     EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
     Button login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
     Button reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
     Button exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);


}
```